# What is naive forecasting?

Tags: time-series, tensorflow2.0, forecasting

I'm doing the Tensorflow course on Udacity and it's started talking about time series forecasting. Here is the Google Colab I'm referencing to: [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l08c02_naive_forecasting.ipynb#scrollTo=JtxwHj9Ig0jT)

This specific line confuses me: naive_forecast = series[split_time - 1:-1]
How does this predict the time series? It's not even using a model, so I'm confused if I even understand what naive forecasting is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive forecast is the prediction that whatever I saw last will be the next thing I see. If February was cold, March will probably be too; if March was warm, chances are April will be warm as well. I.e. for each timepoint in the observed past, the naive prediction is the previous datum. The code

```
x_valid = series[split_time:]
naive_forecast = series[split_time - 1:-1]
```

means that

```
naive_forecast[1] == x_valid[0]
naive_forecast[2] == x_valid[1]
...
```